# Who goes first, Barron Geddon or First-Aid Kit?

Tags: hearthstone

In Hearthstone, [Barron Geddon](https://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Baron_Geddon)'s card text says "At the end of your turn, deal 2 damage to ALL other characters."  Meanwhile, the [First Aid Kit](https://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/First_Aid_Kit) passive says "At the end of your turn, restore 2 Health to all friendly characters."

Which one happens first, at the end of the turn?  Does Barron Geddon first deal 2 damage to everyone, then First Aid Kit restore 2 health to all friendly characters?  Or does it happen in the opposite order?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generally speaking, Hearthstone cards resolve in *order of play*. As passive cards are cast at the beginning of the game, a First Aid Kit will *always* be played before a Baron Geddon, so the heal effect will happen first.

This means that one- and two-health minions will die to a Baron Geddon played while a First Aid Kit is active, as opposed to the opposite case, where they would survive.

For more details, you can read [the advanced rulebook](https://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Advanced_rulebook).